# I wanna make a stopwatch with python

Tags: python, tkinter, stopwatch

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

timer = 0

def startTimer():
    if timer == 0:
        time.sleep(1)
    elif (running):
        global timer
        timer += 1
        timeText.configure(text=str(timer))
    window.after(1000, startTimer)
    
def start():
    global running
    running = True
    
def stop():
    global running
    running = False

running = True

window = tk.Tk()


timeText = tk.Label(window, text = '0', font=("Helvetica", 80))
timeText.pack()

startButton = tk.Button(window, text = 'Start', bg='yellow', command=start)
startButton.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)

stopButton = tk.Button(window, text = 'Stop', bg='yellow', command=stop)
stopButton.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)

startTimer()
window.mainloop()
```

I wanted to make a stopwatch with python
but I have question to you to solve this problem.
when I execute this, I can find

```
line 10
global timer
^
SyntaxError: name 'timer' is used prior to global declaration
```

this error.

I tried to make this stopwatch to start without I press start button.
And, I want this stopwatch to start at 0.

Can you change my code to solve the problem?

Comment: Move `global timer` to the line before `if timer==0` in `startTimer` function

Answer (score 0):

In order for the stopwatch to work you should fix two issues:
you must declare as `global` both `running` and `timer`, since both are used in the `startTimer` function, and you should address the infinite loop that happens in the `if timer == 0` part. You see, if when `timer` is 0 all the script does is wait, then it will never increment and thus loop indefinitely. Both issues are fixed by the code below.

```py
def startTimer():
    global timer
    global running
    if timer == 0:
        time.sleep(1)
        timer += 1
    elif running:
        timer += 1
        timeText.configure(text=str(timer))
    window.after(1000, startTimer)
```

Keep in mind though that `tkinter` does not behave well with `time`, generally speaking.

Comment: It doesn't work...
The error has gone but the timer doesn't count.

Comment: @Gryphinx I've edited my answer, take a look at it and let me know what you think.